# Syntax error when trying to set up Python simpleserver and import from directory

Tags: python, syntax, directory, simplehttpserver

Trying to figure out a specific syntax error while trying to set up a SimpleHTTPServer in Python.

I am trying to pull index.html from a directory on my computer. This is currently what I am writing. I get a syntax error with many different variations of this and the arrow is always pointing to the first C:. Do I need to write something before it? Is it wrong? please help.

C:\Users\brandon\prose-webapp>C:\Python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Are you typing that into a Python shell? If so, that's your issue. You need to type it into a cmd shell.

Comment: could you please paste your error message

Comment: unfortunately i dont have 10 recomendations so I cant post pictures. I only have powershell- what should I write there because that phrase isnt working there either